# Show the reputation for all sites in the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Tags: feature-request, reputation, stack-exchange-button

Currently, only the sites under "Your Communities" section of the drop down show the reputation one got on those sites. If one has account on many sites, and want to quickly know their reputation in one of them, if it's not listed there the only way is to browse to  that site.

I suggest to simply show the reputation for all sites in the Stack Exchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ under "more stack exchange communities":

> [image]

Sites where there's no associated account will stay blank, not show 0. Can this please be done?